# bash, "make clean" in all subdirectories

Tags: bash

How can I find every `Makefile` file in the current path and subdirs and run a `make clean` command in every occurance.

What I have till now (does not work) is something like:

```
find . -type f -name 'Makefile' 2>/dev/null | sed 's@/Makefile@@' | xargs -I% cd % && make clean && cd -
```

Another option would be to use `find` with `-execdir` but this gives me the issue with `$PATH` : `The current directory is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find ....` 
But I do not want to change the `$PATH` variable.

An answer using the tools I used would be helpful so that I can understand what I do wrong, 
but any working answer is acceptable.

Comment: You **should** change the `$PATH` variable. Having `.` in the `PATH` is generally not a good idea. That said that's not the real problem that's just `find` trying to protect you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course find is an option..  My approach with that would be more like:

```
find . -name Makefile -exec bash -c 'make -C "${1%/*}" clean' -- {} \;
```

But since you're using bash anyway, if you're in bash 4, you might also use globstar.

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/Makefile; do make -C "${f%/*}" clean; done
```

Comment: this worked out best for me.  The other answers are very good, but they sometimes do not work out if I am one folder above (../)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the execution feature of `find` you can still do this:

```
 find "${PWD}" -name Makefile -exec sh -c 'cd "${0%Makefile}" && make clean' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following approach:

```
find "$(pwd)" -name Makefile | while read -r line; do cd "$(dirname "$line")" && make clean; done
```

Please note the `find $(pwd)` which gives the full path as output of `find`.

Comment: And around the `$(pwd)` as well. Fixed it.

Comment: True though using `"$PWD"` or `.` are both better then shelling out to `pwd`.

Comment: `.` does not give full paths, which makes the multiple `cd` more complicated. $PWD would be better indeed.

Comment: True, non-subshell `cd` is more complicated. Luckily you can avoid `cd` entirely with `make -C directory`.